# Paypal Checkout as Guest returning something went wrong after submit

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've implemented paypal checkout button. it was working fine in sandbox mode.

Currently we have live option enabled.
When user select pay with Credit card or debit card. and after filling all detail.

When click on `Continue as guest`. it is returning `Sorry, Something went wrong. please try again`.

Comment: Try a different browser, incognito, or clearing your cookies.

Comment: Thanks @PrestonPHX   there issue with Credit card used for checkout.